# \msg_term:n deprecated error in cas-dc (els-cas)

Tags: errors, els-cas

I was creating a PDF using `cas-dc-template.tex` downloaded from http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/els-cas-templates.zip

However it causes the following error:

> ```
> LaTeX3 Error: '\msg_term:n' deprecated on 2020-01-01. Use '\iow_term:n '.
> ```

The error corresponds to the command `\tnotetext[1]`. It seems that something in `\tnotetext` has been deprecated on 2020-01-01. How can I solve this problem?

The same error message appears for the command `\cortext[1]{Corresponding Author}`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is, as the error message says, that `\msg_term:n` is deprecated. This function along with a couple others were removed from the LaTeX3 kernel because they were not correctly named.

I mailed the Elsevier team responsible for their LaTeX packages and they updated (26-02-2020) the `els-cas-templates` package to address this issue. With an up-to-date system you shouldn't experience this issue.

---

For the next few months (until July 1st, 2020) you can have `\msg_term:n` back by loading `expl3` with `undo-recent-deprecations`:

```
\RequirePackage[undo-recent-deprecations]{expl3}
%
\documentclass{cas-dc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\tnotetext[1]{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I appreciate it.

Comment: This actually broke compilation for me on overleaf. I downloaded the project and compiled locally and I noticed following the message "LaTeX3 Error: '\msg_term:n' deprecated on 2020-01-01. Use '\iow_term:n '." it was asking me to "Press ENTER to continue. Since overleaf compilation runs in the background this seem to just hang. Seems poor design to for a compiler to halt on user input. Not sure why I'm just seeing it now though - maybe overleaf just upgraded the latex compiler?

Comment: @DavidWaterworth The version of `cas-dc` on Overleaf is updated so there is no error (I just tried): what do you mean it broke?  Can you share a link to the project?  On a local system it depends: what do you get when you run `latex '\stop'` on a terminal?  TeX (which is technically not a compiler) was made for usage with a terminal, and user interaction was a major feature.  Nevertheless you can run TeX with `-interaction=nonstopmode` to avoid interaction.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I didn't use the cas-dc from overleaf, I uploaded my own copy - I wasn't actually aware it was included with the overleaf templates (I get very confused which elsevier template to use, elsarticle vs cas-dc). I cannot share the link at this stage sorry.

Comment: latex '\stop' prints a few lines of output and then returns back to the terminal on my workstation (Ubuntu). I'll try add `-interaction=nonstopmode` to my overleaf project.

Comment: @DavidWaterworth My opinion about LaTeX's templates: if you're not required to use `cas-dc` (or `cas-sc`; that's just more of the same), use `elsarticle`: it just works.  `cas-ac/dc` was made in a rush and doesn't seem to be maintained and it is just full of bugs. About sharing the project: I don't expect the entirety of your research paper, of course; I mean a project with some dummy text that reproduces the problem.  And Overleaf runs with `-interaction=nonstopmode` by default.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I'll try and reproduce when I get time. I did try and convert back to elsarticle at one stage, it was more or less the same (although I couldn't see how to add the ORCID's and I wasn't entirely sure what arguments to use as I'm submitting to Advances in Applied Energy and couldn't find specific guidance).

Comment: @DavidWaterworth No rush.  When you get to a compilable example that shows the problem, please [ask a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).  Should you decide to use `elsarticle`, I'm sure it's possible to place the ORCID somehow